# Run linux commands in java

Tags: java

It turned out that this question had been asked before.

Comment: By the way, Java 11 and later comes with an [`HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder ("/bin/ping", "stackoverflow.com").start ();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (process.getInputStream ()));
while (true) {
  String line = reader.readLine ();
  if (line == null) break;
  System.out.println (line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the Runtime exec command

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"ping","website"});

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec_envp.htm